# Resetting counter in ESPER after a particular time period

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing, epl

I have a problem using ESPER EPL view.
I need to count the total entries and even group them, this I have seen is possible through 'NOT' using any view or window in query. But I need to reset the count every hour or every day.

I have used time,time_batch,lenghth etc almost all types of windows but they all give incorrect count. I am only able to get correct count without using any view

```
select irstream symbol, count(symbol), sum(price) from StockTick group by grouping sets (symbol,price)
```

Question- How do I reset the count if I am not using any view/window?

Answer (score 0):

You can reset by declaring a context. For example

```
create context ResettableByEvent start @now end ResetEvent
context ResettableByEvent select count(...), ... from StockTick
```

And then when you want to reset you can send a ResetEvent.

Comment: will try this ...but is there any other way except this?